# Android APP connect to FTP server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, android, networking, ftp

I am attempting to build an Android APP with the ability to connect specified FTP server in Java. The connection operation has been performed in `FTPconnection` class and the network call of FTP has been separated from main thread via `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.

**The experimental implementation**

- Project name: FTPConnectionTest
- `FTPconnection` class implementation

  ```
  package com.example.ftpconnectiontest;

  import android.util.Log;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.InetAddress;
  import java.net.SocketException;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;

  import org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

  public class FTPconnection {

      private native String getHostname();
      private native String getUsername();
      private native String getPassword();

      private static String FTPHostName = "";
      private static final int FTPPort = 21;
      private static String FTPUsername = "";
      private static String FTPPassword = "";

      public FTPconnection()
      {
          FTPHostName = getHostname();
          FTPUsername = getUsername();
          FTPPassword = getPassword();
      }

      public FTPClient connectftp()
      {
          //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761268/6667035
          FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
          try {
              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950845/6667035
              //  The argument of `FTPClient.connect` method is hostname, not URL.
              ftp.connect(FTPHostName, FTPPort);
              boolean status = ftp.login(FTPUsername, FTPPassword);
              if (status)
              {
                  ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                  ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                  ftp.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
              }
              System.out.println("status : " + ftp.getStatus());
          } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (SocketException en) {
              en.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return ftp;
      }
  }
  ```
- `ftpconnectiontest.cpp`: The place where store the authorization information. I am wondering is the design safe enough in general FTP connection application.

  ```
  #include <jni.h>
  #include <string>

  extern "C"
  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_example_ftpconnectiontest_FTPconnection_getHostname(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
      std::string output = "Hostname";
      return env->NewStringUTF(output.c_str());
  }
  extern "C"
  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_example_ftpconnectiontest_FTPconnection_getUsername(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
      std::string output = "Username";
      return env->NewStringUTF(output.c_str());
  }
  extern "C"
  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_example_ftpconnectiontest_FTPconnection_getPassword(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
      std::string output = "Password";
      return env->NewStringUTF(output.c_str());
  }
  ```
- `java.util.concurrent.Executors` class implementation

  ```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            showToast(threadName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            FTPconnection ftpConnect = new FTPconnection();
            FTPClient ftpClient = ftpConnect.connectftp();
            final String LOG_TAG = "executor";
            try {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected()));
                showToast(Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
  ```
- User permission setting

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  ```
- `AndroidManifest.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.ftpconnectiontest">

      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.FTPConnectionTest">
          <activity
              android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:exported="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  </manifest>
  ```
- `build.gradle`

  ```
  plugins {
      id 'com.android.application'
  }

  android {
      compileSdk 31

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.example.ftpconnectiontest"
          minSdk 26
          targetSdk 31
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"

          testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
          externalNativeBuild {
              cmake {
                  cppFlags ''
              }
          }
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
      }
      externalNativeBuild {
          cmake {
              path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
              version '3.18.1'
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net
      implementation group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '20030805.205232'
      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
      implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

`MainActivity.java` implementation:

```
package com.example.ftpconnectiontest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE_CODE = 1;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ftpconnectiontest");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE_CODE);

        FTPConnectionTest();
    }

    private void FTPConnectionTest() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                showToast(threadName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            FTPconnection ftpConnect = new FTPconnection();
            FTPClient ftpClient = ftpConnect.connectftp();
            final String LOG_TAG = "executor";
            try {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected()));
                showToast(Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showToast(@StringRes int res, int duration) {
        showToast(getResources().getString(res), duration);
        return;
    }

    private void showToast(String textInput, int duration)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = textInput;
        //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897386/6667035
        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show());
    }

    // Function to check and request permission.
    public void checkPermission(@NonNull String permission, int requestCode)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            // Requesting the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
        }
        else {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                showToast("Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Comment: I think the only part that it's causing trouble trying to run it's the Executors class implementation, but thus far your project it's great!