# Android APP FTP host profile class implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, android, networking, ftp

This is a follow-up question for [Android APP connect to FTP server in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260576/231235). I am attempting to create a tiny FTP host manager with `FTPHostProfile` class and `FTPHostProfiles` class.

**The experimental implementation**

- Project name: FTPHostManagement
- `FTPHostProfile` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftphostmanagement;

  public class FTPHostProfile {
      private String ProfileName = "";
      private String FTPHostName = "";
      private int FTPPort = 21;
      private String FTPUsername = "";
      private String FTPPassword = "";

      public FTPHostProfile(String hostnameInput, int portInput, String usernameInput, String passwordInput)
      {
          this.ProfileName = FTPHostName;
          this.FTPHostName = hostnameInput;
          this.FTPPort = portInput;
          this.FTPUsername = usernameInput;
          this.FTPPassword = passwordInput;
      }

      public FTPHostProfile(String profileNameInput, String hostnameInput, int portInput, String usernameInput, String passwordInput)
      {
          this.ProfileName = profileNameInput;
          this.FTPHostName = hostnameInput;
          this.FTPPort = portInput;
          this.FTPUsername = usernameInput;
          this.FTPPassword = passwordInput;
      }

      public String GetProfilename()
      {
          return this.ProfileName;
      }

      public String GetHostname()
      {
          return this.FTPHostName;
      }

      public int GetPort()
      {
          return this.FTPPort;
      }

      public String GetUsername()
      {
          return this.FTPUsername;
      }

      public String GetPassword()
      {
          return this.FTPPassword;
      }
  }
  ```
- `FTPHostProfiles` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftphostmanagement;

  import android.util.Log;

  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.stream.Collectors;

  public class FTPHostProfiles {
      private ArrayList<FTPHostProfile> Collection = new ArrayList<>();

      /// Empty constructor
      public FTPHostProfiles()
      {

      }

      /// Single FTPHostProfile handler
      public FTPHostProfiles(FTPHostProfile input)
      {
          this.Collection.add(input);
      }

      /// Multiple FTPHostProfiles handler
      public FTPHostProfiles(ArrayList<FTPHostProfile> input)
      {
          this.Collection = input;
      }

      public FTPHostProfiles(FTPHostProfiles input)
      {
          this.Collection.addAll(input.Collection);
      }

      public FTPHostProfiles AddProfile(FTPHostProfile input)
      {
          this.Collection.add(input);
          return this;
      }

      public FTPHostProfiles AddProfiles(ArrayList<FTPHostProfile> input)
      {
          this.Collection.addAll(input);
          return this;
      }

      public FTPHostProfiles AddProfiles(FTPHostProfiles input)
      {
          this.Collection.addAll(input.Collection);
          return this;
      }

      public FTPHostProfile GetProfile(String profileNameInput)
      {
          var filteredResult = this.Collection.stream().filter(element -> (element.GetProfilename().equals(profileNameInput))).collect(Collectors.toList());
          if (filteredResult.stream().count() >= 1)
          {
              return filteredResult.get(0);
          }
          else
          {
              Log.d("GetProfile", "no such item in stored profiles");
              throw new IllegalStateException("no such item in stored profiles");
          }
      }

  }
  ```
- `FTPconnection` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftphostmanagement;

  import android.util.Log;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.InetAddress;
  import java.net.SocketException;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;

  import org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

  public class FTPconnection {

      FTPHostProfiles mFTPHostProfiles = new FTPHostProfiles();

      public FTPconnection(FTPHostProfiles input)
      {
          this.mFTPHostProfiles = input;
      }

      public FTPClient connectftp(String profilename)
      {
          //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761268/6667035
          FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
          try {
              var FTPHostProfile = mFTPHostProfiles.GetProfile(profilename);

              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950845/6667035
              //  The argument of `FTPClient.connect` method is hostname, not URL.
              ftp.connect(FTPHostProfile.GetHostname(), FTPHostProfile.GetPort());
              boolean status = ftp.login(FTPHostProfile.GetUsername(), FTPHostProfile.GetPassword());
              if (status)
              {
                  ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                  ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                  ftp.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
              }
              System.out.println("status : " + ftp.getStatus());
          } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (SocketException en) {
              en.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return ftp;
      }
  }
  ```
- User permission setting

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  ```
- `AndroidManifest.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.ftphostmanagement">

      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.FTPHostManagement">
          <activity
              android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:exported="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  </manifest>
  ```
- `build.gradle`

  ```
  plugins {
      id 'com.android.application'
  }

  android {
      compileSdk 30

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.example.ftphostmanagement"
          minSdk 26
          targetSdk 30
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"

          testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net
      implementation group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '20030805.205232'
      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
      implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

- `MainActivity.java` implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftphostmanagement;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private FTPClient ftpClient;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          new FtpTask().execute();
      }

      void ShowToast(String Text, int Duration)
      {
          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence text = Text;
          int duration = Duration;

          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
          toast.show();
      }

      //  AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at least one method
      //  `doInBackground(Params...)`, and most often will override a second one `onPostExecute(Result)`
      //  Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask?authuser=4
      //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447497/6667035
      private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPClient> {
          //  `doInBackground` invoked on the background thread immediately after `onPreExecute()`
          //  finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation
          //  that can take a long time. The parameters of the asynchronous task are
          //  passed to this step. The result of the computation must be returned by
          //  this step and will be passed back to the last step. This step can also use
          //  `publishProgress(Progress...)` to publish one or more units of progress.
          //  These values are published on the UI thread, in the `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`
          //  step.
          protected FTPClient doInBackground(Void... args) {
              FTPHostProfiles ftpHostProfiles = new FTPHostProfiles();
              ftpHostProfiles.AddProfile(new FTPHostProfile(  "Profile1",
                      "Hostname1",
                      21,
                      "Username1",
                      "Password1"));
              ftpHostProfiles.AddProfile(new FTPHostProfile(  "Profile2",
                      "Hostname2",
                      21,
                      "Username2",
                      "Password2"));

              FTPconnection ftpConnect = new FTPconnection(ftpHostProfiles);
              FTPClient ftp = ftpConnect.connectftp("Profile1");
              return ftp;
          }

          //  `onPostExecute` invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.
          //  The result of the background computation is passed to this step as
          //  a parameter.
          protected void onPostExecute(FTPClient result) {
              Log.v("FTPTask","FTP connection complete");
              ftpClient = result;
              //Where ftpClient is a instance variable in the main activity
              Log.v("Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected())", Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected()));
              ShowToast(Boolean.toString(ftpClient.isConnected()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Android APP connect to FTP server in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260576/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The `FTPHostProfile` class and `FTPHostProfiles` class implementation is the key part in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important caveat: I know nothing about the Special Android coding conventions that are different from vanilla java.

### General

It's preferable to use lowercase letters for acronyms in class names. `FtpHostProfile` is easier to read than `FTPHostProfile`.

Classes which have not been carefully designed for extension should be final.

It's idiomatic for variable names to start with a lowercase letter. `profileName`, etc.

Variables which do not change after the object is constructed should all be marked `final`. This reduces cognitive load on the reader as they can be confident they will not be reassigned after construction.

It's idiomatic for method names to start with a lowercase letter.

It's idiomatic for curly braces to be on the same line as the method declaration, not a line by themselves.

Prefer using the most generally applicable type on the left hand side of assignments. `List` instead of `ArrayList`, etc.

It's unnecessary to assign variables a value when they will get immediately overwritten in the constructor.

### FTPHostProfile

There's no point in assigning the variables to be `""` if you're just going to overwrite them in both constructors.

In the first constructor, why is profile name getting set to `""` by setting it to the value of `FTPHostName`? If you want it to be blank, make it blank. This is especially confusing because FTPHostName is reassigned on the next line.

Lines longer than a hundred characters or so are hard to read. Consider breaking up the declaration of the second constructor over multiple lines, or at least starting the variable declarations on their own line.

`username` and `hostname` are sometimes written as one word. `Profilename` is not an English word, so it should be broken up as `ProfileName`. The variable names are also inconsistent with the method names.

### FTPHostProfiles

Why does constructor number 3 require that multiple profiles be submitted in an `ArrayList`? What's wrong with a `LinkedList`, or (gasp!) a `Set` of some kind? This constructor should take a `Collection`. Likewise for `addProfiles`.

Directly assigning the `input` of that constructor to `Collection` is a bad idea. You've now lost control of your internals - whoever passed in `input` still has a pointer to it, and can change its contents without the knowledge or consent of this class. Just call `addAll` on your collection - you get the values stored in `input`, and nobody can muck with your collection.

`Collection` is not a great variable name. It's not descriptive, and it collides with a class name. Consider `profiles` or `ftpHostProfiles` as variable names.

Do you actually need both constructors and methods which add profiles? That seems like overkill.

Having the `addProfile` methods `return this` is convenient for chaining, but consider if you need to return something else instead, such as whether the addition was successful or not.

`getProfile` makes it clear that that `profiles` should be a `Map`, not a `List`.

### FTPconnection

The `c` should be capitalized.

`mFtpHostProfiles` should probably be `private final`.

This class has several unused imports.

You can probably call the variable `profile` I think there's enough context that the `FTPHost` is redundant.

Perhaps `loggedIn` would be more descriptive than `status`?

If you made all these changes, your code might look more like:

FtpConnection:

```
public final class FtpConnection {

    private final FtpHostProfiles mFtpHostProfiles = new FtpHostProfiles();

    public FtpConnection(FtpHostProfiles input) {
        this.mFtpHostProfiles.addProfiles(input);
    }

    public FTPClient connectftp(String profileName) {
        //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761268/6667035
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        try {
            FtpHostProfile profile = mFtpHostProfiles.getProfile(profileName);

            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950845/6667035
            //  The argument of `FtpClient.connect` method is hostname, not URL.
            ftp.connect(profile.getHostname(), profile.getPort());
            boolean loggedIn = ftp.login(profile.getUsername(), profile.getPassword());
            if (loggedIn) {
                ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                ftp.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
            }
            System.out.println("status : " + ftp.getStatus());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException en) {
            en.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ftp;
    }
}
```

FtpHostProfile:

```
public final class FtpHostProfile {
    private final String profileName;
    private final String ftpHostName;
    private final int ftpPort;
    private final String ftpUserName;
    private final String ftpPassword;

    public FtpHostProfile(String hostNameInput, int portInput, String userNameInput, String passwordInput) {
        this.profileName = "";
        this.ftpHostName = hostNameInput;
        this.ftpPort = portInput;
        this.ftpUserName = userNameInput;
        this.ftpPassword = passwordInput;
    }
    public FtpHostProfile(
            String profileNameInput,
            String hostnameInput,
            int portInput,
            String usernameInput,
            String passwordInput) {
        this.profileName = profileNameInput;
        this.ftpHostName = hostnameInput;
        this.ftpPort = portInput;
        this.ftpUserName = usernameInput;
        this.ftpPassword = passwordInput;
    }

    public String getProfileName() {
        return this.profileName;
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return this.ftpHostName;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.ftpPort;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.ftpUserName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.ftpPassword;
    }
}
```

FtpHostProfiles:

```
public final class FtpHostProfiles {
    private final Map<String, FtpHostProfile> profiles = new HashMap<>();

    public FtpHostProfiles() {
        // Empty constructor
    }

    public FtpHostProfiles addProfile(FtpHostProfile input) {
        this.profiles.put(input.getProfileName(), input);
        return this;
    }

    public FtpHostProfiles addProfiles(Collection<FtpHostProfile> input) {
        input.stream().forEach(profile -> profiles.put(profile.getProfileName(), profile));
        return this;
    }

    public FtpHostProfiles addProfiles(FtpHostProfiles input) {
        this.profiles.putAll(input.profiles);
        return this;
    }

    public FtpHostProfile getProfile(String profileNameInput) {
        FtpHostProfile profile = profiles.get(profileNameInput);
        if (profile == null) {
            Log.d("GetProfile", "No such item in stored profiles");
            throw new IllegalStateException("No such item in stored profiles");
        }
        return profile;
    }

}
```