# Android APP FTP uploading file implementation in Java

Tags: java, android, file, error-handling, ftp

This is a follow-up question for [Android APP FTP host profile class implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261109/231235) and [Android APP connect to FTP server in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260576/231235). I am attempting to perform the upload operation to specified FTP server in Android APP. With referring to [the answer of FtpClient storeFile always return False](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8154539/6667035) and [List of FTP server return codes on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes), the returned reply code is translated to `string` message.

**The experimental implementation**

- `FtpConnection` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftpreplycodeclass;

  import android.util.Log;

  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
  import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.SocketException;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;

  public final class FtpConnection {

      private final FtpHostProfiles ftpHostProfiles = new FtpHostProfiles();

      public FtpConnection(FtpHostProfiles input) {
          this.ftpHostProfiles.addProfiles(input);
      }

      public boolean uploadFile(String profileName, String fullFilename) {
          File targetFile = new File(fullFilename);
          if (!targetFile.exists()) {
              Log.e("FTPconnection_uploadFile", "File " + fullFilename + " isn't existed!");
              return false;
          }

          //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761268/6667035
          FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
          try {
              FtpHostProfile profile = ftpHostProfiles.getProfile(profileName);

              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950845/6667035
              //  The argument of `FTPClient.connect` method is hostname, not URL.
              ftp.connect(profile.getHostname(), profile.getPort());
              boolean status = ftp.login(profile.getUsername(), profile.getPassword());
              if (status)
              {
                  ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                  ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                  ftp.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
              }
              System.out.println("status : " + ftp.getStatus());
              Log.d("FTPTask", ftp.getStatus());
              FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fullFilename);
              String filename = new File(fullFilename).getName();
              boolean result = ftp.storeFile(filename, in);
              var detailedInfo = ftp.getReplyCode();
              Log.d("FTP Reply Code", String.valueOf(detailedInfo));
              Log.d("FTP Reply Message", FtpReplyCode.getReplyMessage(detailedInfo));
              in.close();
              ftp.logout();
              ftp.disconnect();
              return result;
          } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (SocketException en) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              en.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return false;
      }

      public FTPClient connectftp(String profileName) {
          //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761268/6667035
          FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
          try {
              FtpHostProfile profile = ftpHostProfiles.getProfile(profileName);

              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950845/6667035
              //  The argument of `FtpClient.connect` method is hostname, not URL.
              ftp.connect(profile.getHostname(), profile.getPort());
              boolean loggedIn = ftp.login(profile.getUsername(), profile.getPassword());
              if (loggedIn) {
                  ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                  ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                  ftp.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");
              }
              System.out.println("status : " + ftp.getStatus());
          } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (SocketException en) {
              en.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return ftp;
      }

      private static class FtpReplyCode {

          private static String getReplyMessage(int input) {
              if (input == 100) {
                  return "The requested action is being initiated, expect another reply before proceeding with a new command.";
              }
              if (input == 110) {
                  return "Restart marker replay.";
              }
              if (input == 120) {
                  return "Service ready in nnn minutes.";
              }
              if (input == 125) {
                  return "Data connection already open; transfer starting.";
              }
              if (input == 150) {
                  return "File status okay; about to open data connection.";
              }
              if (input == 200) {
                  return "The requested action has been successfully completed.";
              }
              if (input == 202) {
                  return "Command not implemented, superfluous at this site.";
              }
              if (input == 211) {
                  return "System status, or system help reply.";
              }
              if (input == 212) {
                  return "Directory status.";
              }
              if (input == 213) {
                  return "File status.";
              }
              if (input == 214) {
                  return "Help message. Explains how to use the server or the meaning of a particular non-standard command. This reply is useful only to the human user.";
              }
              if (input == 215) {
                  return "NAME system type. Where NAME is an official system name from the registry kept by IANA.";
              }
              if (input == 220) {
                  return "Service ready for new user.";
              }
              if (input == 221) {
                  return "Service closing control connection.";
              }
              if (input == 225) {
                  return "Data connection open; no transfer in progress.";
              }
              if (input == 226) {
                  return "Closing data connection. Requested file action successful (for example, file transfer or file abort).";
              }
              if (input == 227) {
                  return "Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2).";
              }
              if (input == 228) {
                  return "Entering Long Passive Mode (long address, port).";
              }
              if (input == 229) {
                  return "Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||port|).";
              }
              if (input == 230) {
                  return "User logged in, proceed. Logged out if appropriate.";
              }
              if (input == 231) {
                  return "User logged out; service terminated.";
              }
              if (input == 232) {
                  return "Logout command noted, will complete when transfer done.";
              }
              if (input == 234) {
                  return "Specifies that the server accepts the authentication mechanism specified by the client, and the exchange of security data is complete. A higher level nonstandard code created by Microsoft.";
              }
              if (input == 250) {
                  return "Requested file action okay, completed.";
              }
              if (input == 257) {
                  return "\"PATHNAME\" created";
              }
              if (input == 300) {
                  return "The command has been accepted, but the requested action is on hold, pending receipt of further information.";
              }
              if (input == 331) {
                  return "User name okay, need password.";
              }
              if (input == 332) {
                  return "Need account for login.";
              }
              if (input == 350) {
                  return "Requested file action pending further information";
              }
              if (input == 400) {
                  return "The command was not accepted and the requested action did not take place, but the error condition is temporary and the action may be requested again.";
              }
              if (input == 421) {
                  return "Service not available, closing control connection. This may be a reply to any command if the service knows it must shut down.";
              }
              if (input == 425) {
                  return "Can\'t open data connection.";
              }
              if (input == 426) {
                  return "Connection closed; transfer aborted.";
              }
              if (input == 430) {
                  return "Invalid username or password";
              }
              if (input == 434) {
                  return "Requested host unavailable.";
              }
              if (input == 450) {
                  return "Requested file action not taken.";
              }
              if (input == 451) {
                  return "Requested action aborted. Local error in processing.";
              }
              if (input == 452) {
                  return "Requested action not taken. Insufficient storage space in system. File unavailable (e.g., file busy).";
              }
              if (input == 500) {
                  return "Syntax error, command unrecognized and the requested action did not take place. This may include errors such as command line too long.";
              }
              if (input == 501) {
                  return "Syntax error in parameters or arguments.";
              }
              if (input == 502) {
                  return "Command not implemented.";
              }
              if (input == 503) {
                  return "Bad sequence of commands.";
              }
              if (input == 504) {
                  return "Command not implemented for that parameter.";
              }
              if (input == 530) {
                  return "Not logged in.";
              }
              if (input == 532) {
                  return "Need account for storing files.";
              }
              if (input == 534) {
                  return "Could Not Connect to Server - Policy Requires SSL";
              }
              if (input == 550) {
                  return "Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).";
              }
              if (input == 551) {
                  return "Requested action aborted. Page type unknown.";
              }
              if (input == 552) {
                  return "Requested file action aborted. Exceeded storage allocation (for current directory or dataset).";
              }
              if (input == 553) {
                  return "Requested action not taken. File name not allowed.";
              }
              if (input == 600) {
                  return "Replies regarding confidentiality and integrity";
              }
              if (input == 631) {
                  return "Integrity protected reply.";
              }
              if (input == 632) {
                  return "Confidentiality and integrity protected reply.";
              }
              if (input == 633) {
                  return "Confidentiality protected reply.";
              }
              if (input == 10000) {
                  return "Common Winsock Error Codes";
              }
              if (input == 10054) {
                  return "Connection reset by peer. The connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.";
              }
              if (input == 10060) {
                  return "Cannot connect to remote server.";
              }
              if (input == 10061) {
                  return "Cannot connect to remote server. The connection is actively refused by the server.";
              }
              if (input == 10066) {
                  return "Directory not empty.";
              }
              if (input == 10068) {
                  return "Too many users, server is full.";
              }
              return "";
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

- `MainActivity.java` implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftpreplycodeclass;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

  import android.Manifest;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Calendar;
  import java.util.TimeZone;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE = 1;
      private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE = 2;
      private static final int ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE_CODE = 3;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
          checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
          checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE_CODE);

          User currentUser = new User(
                  "Mike",
                  "M12345678",
                  "1990/10/13",
                  "(555) 555-1234",
                  "123456@test.com",
                  "password");

          //  Using GMT (UTC±00:00) time
          var gmtTimeZone = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
          gmtTimeZone.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
          String currentTime = gmtTimeZone.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
          String newUserRegistrationFilename = currentTime + "_NewUser.ser";
          boolean isSaveSuccessfully = Serialization.Save(this, newUserRegistrationFilename, currentUser);
          if (isSaveSuccessfully) {
              showToast("Save current user information successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
              Log.d("Save operation", "Save current user information successfully");
          }
          showToast(Serialization.Load(this, newUserRegistrationFilename).getFullName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          new FtpTask().execute(this.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/files/" + newUserRegistrationFilename);


      }

      // Function to check and request permission.
      public void checkPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
          if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

              // Requesting the permission
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
          }
          else {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }

      void showToast(String textInput, int duration) {
          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence text = textInput;
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
          toast.show();
      }

      //  AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at least one method
      //  `doInBackground(Params...)`, and most often will override a second one `onPostExecute(Result)`
      //  Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask?authuser=4
      //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447497/6667035
      private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
          //  `doInBackground` invoked on the background thread immediately after `onPreExecute()`
          //  finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation
          //  that can take a long time. The parameters of the asynchronous task are
          //  passed to this step. The result of the computation must be returned by
          //  this step and will be passed back to the last step. This step can also use
          //  `publishProgress(Progress...)` to publish one or more units of progress.
          //  These values are published on the UI thread, in the `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`
          //  step.
          protected Boolean doInBackground(String... filenames) {
              FtpHostProfiles ftpHostProfiles = new FtpHostProfiles();
              ftpHostProfiles.addProfile(new FtpHostProfile(
                      "Profile1",
                      "Hostname1",
                      21,
                      "Username1",
                      "Password1"));
              ftpHostProfiles.addProfile(new FtpHostProfile(
                      "Profile2",
                      "Hostname2",
                      21,
                      "Username2",
                      "Password2"));

              FtpConnection ftpConnect = new FtpConnection(ftpHostProfiles);
              for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
                  Log.v("FTPTask","Preparing to upload " + filenames[i]);
                  var result  = ftpConnect.uploadFile("Profile1", filenames[i]);
                  if (result == false) {
                      Log.v("FTPTask","Fail to upload " + filenames[i] + "!");
                      return false;
                  } else {
                      Log.v("FTPTask","Upload " + filenames[i] + " successfully!");
                  }
                  if (isCancelled()) break;
              }
              return true;
          }

          //  `onPostExecute` invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.
          //  The result of the background computation is passed to this step as
          //  a parameter.
          protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
              if (result) {
                  Log.v("FTPTask","FTP upload complete");
              }
              return;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `User` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftpreplycodeclass;

  import java.security.MessageDigest;
  import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

  public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {
      private String fullName;
      private String personalID;
      private String dateOfBirth;
      private String cellPhoneNumber;
      private String emailInfo;
      private String password;


      public User(final String fullNameInput,
                  final String personalIDInput,
                  final String dateOfBirthInput,
                  final String cellPhoneNumberInput,
                  final String emailInfoInput,
                  final String passwordInput) {
          fullName = fullNameInput;
          personalID = personalIDInput;
          dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthInput;
          cellPhoneNumber = cellPhoneNumberInput;
          emailInfo = emailInfoInput;
          try {
              password = hashingMethod(passwordInput);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              password = passwordInput;
          }
          return;
      }

      public String getFullName() {
          return fullName;
      }

      public String getPersonalID() {
          return personalID;
      }

      public String getDateOfBirth() {
          return dateOfBirth;
      }

      public String getCellPhoneNumber() {
          return cellPhoneNumber;
      }

      public String getEmailInfo() {
          return emailInfo;
      }

      public String getHash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
          return hashingMethod(fullName + personalID);
      }

      public String getHashedPassword() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
          return password;
      }

      public boolean checkPassword(String password) {
          boolean result = false;
          try {
              result = password.equals(hashingMethod(password));
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return result;
      }

      //**********************************************************************************************

      //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624385/6667035
      private String hashingMethod(String inputString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
          MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
          String stringToHash = inputString;
          messageDigest.update(stringToHash.getBytes());
          String stringHash = new String(messageDigest.digest());
          return stringHash;
      }
  }
  ```
- `Serialization` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftpreplycodeclass;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.Log;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
  import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

  //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260909/231235
  public class Serialization {

      //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118917/6667035
      //  fileName cannot contain any path separator
      public static boolean Save(Context context, String fileName, User user) {
          try {
              FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              String fullFilename = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName;
              Log.d("Save", "Save file in " + fullFilename);
              ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
              os.writeObject(user);
              os.close();
              fos.close();
              if (new File(fullFilename).exists()) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          } catch (IOException i) {
              i.printStackTrace();
              return false;
          }
      }

      public static User Load(Context context, String fileName) {
          try {
              FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
              ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
              User simpleClass = (User) is.readObject();
              is.close();
              fis.close();
              return simpleClass;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- `FtpHostProfile` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftpreplycodeclass;

  public final class FtpHostProfile {
      private final String profileName;
      private final String ftpHostName;
      private final int ftpPort;
      private final String ftpUserName;
      private final String ftpPassword;

      public FtpHostProfile(String hostNameInput, int portInput, String userNameInput, String passwordInput) {
          this.profileName = "";
          this.ftpHostName = hostNameInput;
          this.ftpPort = portInput;
          this.ftpUserName = userNameInput;
          this.ftpPassword = passwordInput;
      }
      public FtpHostProfile(
              String profileNameInput,
              String hostnameInput,
              int portInput,
              String usernameInput,
              String passwordInput) {
          this.profileName = profileNameInput;
          this.ftpHostName = hostnameInput;
          this.ftpPort = portInput;
          this.ftpUserName = usernameInput;
          this.ftpPassword = passwordInput;
      }

      public String getProfileName() {
          return this.profileName;
      }

      public String getHostname() {
          return this.ftpHostName;
      }

      public int getPort() {
          return this.ftpPort;
      }

      public String getUsername() {
          return this.ftpUserName;
      }

      public String getPassword() {
          return this.ftpPassword;
      }
  }
  ```
- `FtpHostProfiles` class implementation:

  ```
  package com.example.ftpreplycodeclass;

  import android.util.Log;

  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  public final class FtpHostProfiles {
      private final Map<String, FtpHostProfile> profiles = new HashMap<>();

      public FtpHostProfiles() {
          // Empty constructor
      }

      public FtpHostProfiles addProfile(FtpHostProfile input) {
          this.profiles.put(input.getProfileName(), input);
          return this;
      }

      public FtpHostProfiles addProfiles(Collection<FtpHostProfile> input) {
          input.stream().forEach(profile -> profiles.put(profile.getProfileName(), profile));
          return this;
      }

      public FtpHostProfiles addProfiles(FtpHostProfiles input) {
          this.profiles.putAll(input.profiles);
          return this;
      }

      public FtpHostProfile getProfile(String profileNameInput) {
          FtpHostProfile profile = profiles.get(profileNameInput);
          if (profile == null) {
              Log.d("GetProfile", "No such item in stored profiles");
              throw new IllegalStateException("No such item in stored profiles");
          }
          return profile;
      }

  }
  ```
- `AndroidManifest.xml`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.ftpreplycodeclass">

      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.FtpReplyCodeClass">
          <activity
              android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:exported="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  </manifest>
  ```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Android APP FTP host profile class implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261109/231235) and

  [Android APP connect to FTP server in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260576/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am attempting to perform the upload operation to specified FTP server in Android APP in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FtpConnection

- You're duplicating `connectftp` in `uploadFile`. `uploadFile` should probably call `connectftp` rather than re-implement it itself
- On that note, consider whether or not it makes sense to have construction and connection be two separate steps. While that is often a valid approach, having your class represent an *open* connection may sometimes be more natural
- The name `connectftp` is a bit redundant, isn't it? Having an `FtpConnection` class with a `connect` method seems clear enough to me

### FtpReplyCode

- I'm not sure `""` is an appropriate response for unknown reply codes. If your program doesn't understand what the FTP server is asking for, I think that should be made more obvious. Maybe with an exception, or maybe by having `getReplyMessage` return an `Optional<String>` instead of a `String`.
- While there's nothing *wrong* with having a chain of `if`s like that, you're really just mapping some inputs to some outputs in a really straightforward way. Having a lookup table in the form of a `Map<Integer, String>` could be more flexible

### User

- I'm not sure if silently storing the password un-hashed if hashing fails is the best idea. It doesn't seem likely to fail, but if it does, you'd probably want to know
- Why is `getHashedPassword` declared as `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException`?

### Serialization

- You can get the file path using `context.getFileStreamPath(fileName)`
- If something goes wrong during saving or loading, you might not end up closing the input/output streams. You might want to use `try-with-resources` statements to make sure they do get closed
- Method names should usually begin with a lowercase letter, so `save` and `load` rather than `Save` and `Load`

### FtpHostProfile / FtpHostProfiles

- Do the profiles need to know their own names? Maybe they do, but if they don't, you might be able to have the names only exist in the context of a `FtpHostProfiles`, which could then go from needing a distinct class to just being a `Map<String, FtpHostProfile>`